# Why isnt my jquery working when I use external pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using jquery to load in 2 external pages, one called search.php and the other is called info.php. I am displaying them each on a single page called user.php but only when there link has been clicked in the navigation bar. Unfortunately I am currently experiencing a problem, when I use this section of script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#content_area').load($('.menu_top:first').attr('href'));
});


$('.menu_top').click(function() {
var href = $(this).attr('href');
$('#content_area').hide().load(href).fadeIn('normal');

return false;
});
```

My page seems to flicker and stall for 2 seconds before changing the content. I have noticed However if I remove the .hide and fadeIn it seems to work fine. How can I still use the fade-in but eliminate the stall and flickering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery adds .fadeIn, .hide, and other effects to it's effect's queue. So it's calling .load() instantly JUST AFTER it sends the .hide to the effect's queue/and the .hide isn't completed.

You can do a callback on the .hide method:

```
$('#content_area').hide(function(){
    $('#content_area').load(href).fadeIn('normal');
})
```

This allows hide to finish first.

Answer (score 1):

try experimenting with .stop to see if it helps with flickering:

```
$('#content_area').hide().stop(true,true).load(href).stop(true,true).fadeIn('normal');
```

Answer (score 0):

for flickering use `animate` instead of `fadeIn` or `fadeOut`

for fadeout

```
  $("youeSelector").animate({ opacity: 0 }, 'slow');
```

for fadein

```
  $("youeSelector").animate({ opacity: 1 }, 'slow');
```

and as far as the second problem goes make sure you are not including the script files twice